# Ruby on rails - unable to create comments. NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, ruby-on-rails-5

I am creating one of my first RoR applications - a forum. I am try to add comments to the forum, but I am getting some errors. I have Googled for similar issues but none of the seem to solve my issue. Here is my code:

Comments Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])

    if !@forum.nil?
        puts "Forum object is not nil"
    end

    @comment = @forum.comment.create(comment_params)

    redirect_to forum_path
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

The Forum controller is auto generated and I haven't changed in. (generated using rails generate scaffold Forum, if you still want to see it, let me know)

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :forum
end

class Forum < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  validates :title, presence: true,
  length: {maximum: 50}
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

Below is the form for section from the show.html.erb **for the forum page**

```
<h2>Comments</h2>

<% @forum.comments.each do |comment| %>
<p>
    <%= comment.body %>
</p>

<% end %>

<h2>Add a comment</h2>

<%= form_for([@forum, @forum.comments.build]) do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

And this is the error from rails:

```
undefined method `comment' for #<Forum:0x444d518>
```

with the following extract:

```
end
 @comment = @forum.comment.create(comment_params) #highlighted
 redirect_to forum_path
end
```

Comment: 1) Rails 3 is way out of date. 2) Please format your post.

Comment: I agree with coreward, If this is a new app, I'd recommend using Rails 5.  If you want a slightly older version, use the latest Rails 4.  BTW, the fact that your model  class inherits from `ApplicationRecord` leads me to believe you  are using Rails 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem lay in the CommentsController.

I changed the comments controller to do this instead:

```
def create
        @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])

        @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
        @comment.forum_id = @forum.id
        @comment.save!

        redirect_to forum_path(@forum)
    end


    private
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
        end
```

Seemed to do the trick.

Thank you to all those who gave an answer.

Comment: There is a better way to do this. Please check my answer.

Comment: rather use `@comment = @forum.comments.new(comment_params)` and `@comment.save`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be missing a `has_many :comments` association in your Forum model.  Check it out.

Alternatively if the has_many association exits then it allows you to call 'comments' on any Forum object, not 'comment'.

if you want to create a comment for a particular forum you can do so like this:

```
@comment = Comment.create(comment_params) #create a comment associated with this forum.
```

Comment: It has this. I checked

Comment: Doing what you suggested gives this error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been a bit busy.  Let me know if the edited version works.  Basically just passing in the strong comment_params to the create method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line `@comment = @forum.comment.create(comment_params)` in your CommentsController.
It should be `@comment = @forum.comments.create(comment_params)` . `comments` should be plural.

Your code should be:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @comment = @forum.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to forum_path
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `comments` association in the `Forum` model:

```
class Forum < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```